# Comparing Composer Names, Or How do I find a 'close enough' match between two strings?

Tags: java, string

After finishing two cs classes, I've started working on a personal project in Java.  I am writing a program that will look through a music collection and attempt to set the 'Composer' tag by looking at the filename and meta tags.  I am comparing these against a composer list I have created as a simple text file.  My question is this:

What is a good method for comparing two strings to try to find a best match of sorts?  For exammple, in my case suppose I have a file called 'Pulenc - Gloria in excelsis Deo.flac'.  In my composer list I have 'Poulenc, Francis'.  I want to be able to read 'Pulenc', and see that it is very close to 'Poulenc' so that I can have the composer tag set correctly.  A friend suggested I look into using Cosine Distance (which I'd never heard of before), and another recommended Levenshtein Distance.  Are either of these a good approach or are there other methods that may work better?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like the [Levenshtein Distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) is exactly what you need. The [Cosine Distance](http://www.comp.rgu.ac.uk/staff/sy/PhD_Thesis_html/page_67.htm) seems to deal with longer texts, and [phonetic algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonetic_algorithm) like Soundex will probably yield poor results for names, most of which are not intended to be pronounced using English pronounciation rules.

Answer (score 2):

There's a [project called SimMetrics](http://sourceforge.net/projects/simmetrics/), run by the [University of Sheffield](http://nlp.shef.ac.uk/wig/) in the UK that will be able to help you out.  I wrote a little bit about it [in my blog](http://chillijam.co.uk/2009/05/13/fuzzy-matching-of-names/) from a .NET point of view, but I believe the project also has a Java implementation available.

Answer (score 0):

[Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) is a reasonable idea, although if you have a lot of composers in your system, it may perform badly. Unlike [Soundex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundex) (or [Metaphone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaphone), or [NYSIIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_York_State_Identification_and_Intelligence_System)), edit distance algorithms make you compare your misspelled composer name to every other composer in the system. Depending on how many there are, this could take a while.

As a (premature?) optimisation, it may be worth only computing Levenshtein distance for composers whose name starts with the right letter.

Answer (score 0):

Peter Norvig has written an excellent piece, ["How to Write a Spelling Corrector"](http://norvig.com/spell-correct.html), that you may find useful, and that you can tweak to your specific needs.

Answer (score 0):

By the way, the Apache Commons Lang lib implements a Levenshtein Distance calculator: http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#getLevenshteinDistance(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)

Answer (score 0):

I think in your case [Damerau–Levenshtein distanc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damerau%E2%80%93Levenshtein_distance)e should work fine. If you have more data, use it. In the absence of good algorithm, large amount of data can compensate.